# Integration of Fabric SDK for twitter in android with eclipse juno

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

While integrating Fabric Sdk for Twitter in my Android Application I followed the Step as per Febric website but after plugin in Eclipse Juno Ver 23.0.0.1245622 getting problem.

My Eclipse getting closed while login in Fabric(The first step after plugin fabric in eclipse juno 23.0.0.1245622 .)